# Live data analysis

Tags: logging, bigdata, analysis, live, data-processing

There's an application running and I need to pull data from the application for analysis. I have a couple of questions:

If a log of the information is generating as the application runs, and  open the file for reading and grab the newest line, is there any interference? What's the proper way to do this.

When reading from a log file that's actively logging application data, I need to keep track of the rows so I don't grab duplicate data? What's the best practice of doing this? What if data is generating at a fast rate: 1000 lines per second.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at "flume" tool. It will handle everything for you.